# PHP arrow operator closing tags

Tags: php, apache

I am writing a php app on the websever I set up at my house.  It is a fedora10 machine, running php5 and mysql.  I have code like this:

```
<?php echo $var->function(); ?>
```

But for some reason the -> is closing the php tag, so the output has 'function(); ?' added to it...is there something I need to change in my php or webserver configuration?

Comment: Is the page actually being read by PHP?

Comment: yes...using regular, non-OO php works just fine

Comment: It supposed to work. How about if you put those in different lines? Or delete the whole thing, and re-type it again.

Comment: I have this problem in my editor, but not in php itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think that you have mod_php enabled in your apache config file, or else you would never see the php code in the output.  [Here is a good tutorial](http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html) on setting up php 5 in apache.

Comment: i think, shane is right. the php code is interpreted as html. in your source you should see the php-code 1 by 1 - nothing is interpreted. the `function()` is displayed because `<?php and ->` act as html-open and -close tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php echo("foo"); ?>
```

If that doesn't work, you don't have PHP enabled in Apache.

Comment: yes, php is enabled, I have been using it for a while, just never with any 'OO' php stuff before

Answer (score 0):

If your're sure that php is enabled, try this one

```
<?php
$result = $var -> function();
echo $result;
?>
```

to debug it a little.. maybe something interesting will raise

Answer (score 0):

Is the php enabled on server? A simple test for determining it:

`<?php` `phpinfo();?>`

Put the above line in a .php file and access it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Final closing php tag isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem the other day but I was using
    bar ?>
instead of
    bar; ?>

It turned out that the `short_open_tag` option was disabled in my PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a standard XAMPP installation.

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Solved it.