# PHP script closes unexpectedly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem:
I have a wordpress website and I do the next simple action:

```
$acm = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `some_table`');
```

And the problem is that server closes php script at -> and then the code

```
get_results('SELECT * FROM `some_table`');
```

becomes a simple html.

Why can it be and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked your webserver error logs?  Also, is this a *working* Wordpress installation?  Like, did it work properly before you started editing / adding code?

Comment: *"becomes a simple html"* - (?)

Comment: the script is crashing, or your php isn't working at all and the `->` is seen as a closing html tag?

Comment: There are several things potentially wrong. First and foremost, is the file saved with a `.php` extension?

Comment: Error logs are clean, yes it was working noramlly before. It's not crashing, it just cuts the php code on -> place. Yes, the file is saved as php, otherwise it wouldn't do any of that code

Comment: Probably won't do anything, but try using double quotes instead of singles for your SELECT. `get_results("SELECT * FROM some_table");` @Ivan

Comment: It's not the problem of quotes, it's problem of apache seeing -> as the end of php code.

Comment: Can you create a simple `test.php` file, place this code inside `<?php class test{public function something(){return 'i got in!';}} $myClass = new test(); echo $myClass->something(); ?>` <-- this last line will tell you if Apache/PHP is having an issue with `->`

Answer (score 0):

you have to activate "mod_php" in your apache config file. Look here :

[PHP arrow operator closing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736450/php-arrow-operator-closing-tags)

Comment: Can I somehow activate it through php? Cuz I'm not sure I have an access to config file.

Comment: Do you give the good extension of your file? Create a file "index.php" in the good folder (wwwroot? www?) and put in <?php phpinfo(); ?>