# Raspberry php -> Operator not working

Tags: php, apache

I installed apache2 and php5 on my raspberry pi. This example works:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

but when I try to use the -> Operator, the website shows me my source code and doesn't execute the code:

Also it looks like the -> is acting as html code: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736450/php-arrow-operator-closing-tags)
But php5 is turned on

```
include_once 'status.class.php';
$status = new ServerStatus();
$response = $status->getStatus('');//hidden adress
if(!$response) {
    echo"The Server is offline!";
}
```

What is wrong?

everything under the "->" will be shown as code.
in php file it works correctly

Comment: Show us the code with `->` operator. We can't imagine it.

Comment: Did you forget the <?php while quoting or is it missed in your file?

Comment: no I have it and apache is allowed to access the files

Comment: @Ermodo File extension is the same for your phpinfo() and getstatus file? What's the exact output of your second file? What happens when you comment out or remove the 3rd line?

Comment: @clemens321 when I remove it, the site doesn't show anything. Also file endings are same

Comment: @Ermodo Enable error reporting and display errors, there should be at least a noticed about not defined $response, propably much more.

Comment: edit: when I use the code above in a php-file, it works. But when I use it within my html-code it doesn't

Comment: ...so, what is the full content and name with extension of the file which doesn't work...

Comment: long story short, when I use the "->", a part of the php code is acting as html. But when I have an empty php, with only this code in it and call it, the

Comment: echo is shown. (in Html not)

Comment: Please show source in your browser. What's the first after <article> you can see? I assume the problem is not your "->" but anything inside ('') you are not showing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/yQmEiE1     view-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your html file to anything.php - not .htm(l)

Your PHP parser is not working at all, independent if the -> is inside or not.

The only difference is, if -> is in, your browser treats everything between  (read < and >) as invalid html tag and hides it. If you omit the closing > it is shown. In view-source it is in both cases.

Comment: thx, it's working now, but then I need to have the .php in the url. Is there a way to fix this (so that there is no file-ending)?

Comment: Edit:  adding this to the htaccess seems to work:                        RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html